# Chrome browser Format date with remove T and time when time is zero other answers are NOT working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, datetime

Chrome browser is showing wrong day while Firefox is showing the correct day

I am using code that people have upvoted many times

F12 and run this fiddle in both Chrome and Firefox, I only care about Chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/foag0zew/

```
//This works fine to convert 
var dateString = "2015-10-14T17:54:19.033";
```

**Having NO time and this ends up not working  shows   10/27/15 instead of the correct 10/28/15**

```
var dateString2 = "2015-10-28T00:00:00";
```

Code (in fiddle as well)

```
var dateString2 = "2015-10-28T00:00:00";
var date2 = new Date(dateString2);
var formattedDateString2 = (date2.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date2.getDate() + "/" + date2.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
console.log(formattedDateString2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually due to some recent changes in Chrome over supporting ES6 spec properly.  See Chromium issues [539813](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539813) and [543320](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543320), and [ECMAScript tc39 issue 87](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87)

Basically what happened is:

- ES5 used to specify that strings in ISO format without an offset were to be treated as UTC, but no implementations honored that because by ISO8601 it should default to local, not UTC.  So, that was fixed in ES6.
- Chrome implemented the change, as previously date-only values were interpreted as UTC, though date+time values were interpreted as local time.
- Chrome decided to *revert* the change and go back to old behavior.  Personally, I think that was a mistake - but others disagree.
- When they reverted the change, they inadvertently switched *both* the date-only value and the date+time values back to UTC defaults, instead of just the date-only value.  So now, your date+time value is being interpreted in UTC instead of in local time.

To force it to be interpreted as local time requires some string replacements.  This should work:

```
var s1 = "2015-10-28T00:00:00";
var s2 = s1.replace(/-/g,'/').replace('T',' '); // "2015/10/28 00:00:00"
var d = new Date(s2); // now will parse as local in all browsers
```

Comment: Wow,  great explanation